# Output in case of chaining inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

```
class Monster {
    boolean frighten(int x) {
        System.out.println("Monster");
        return true;
    }
}

class Vampire extends Monster {
    boolean frighten(byte x) {
        System.out.println("Vampire");
        return true;
    }
}

class Dragon extends Monster {
    boolean frighten(int x) {
        System.out.println("Dragon");
        return true;
    }
}


class Sample {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        Monster[] inst = new Monster[3];
        inst[0] = new Monster();
        inst[1] = new Vampire();
        inst[2] = new Dragon();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            inst[i].frighten(i);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above code with `x` as `int` in `Monster` or `Dragon` class, the code works fine in the way I expect.  However, when I run the code by changing the type of `x` from `int` to `long` either in `Monster` or `Dragon` classes, it prints the following:

```
Monster                           
Monster                                 
Monster
```

Can someone explain the logic behind the output?

Comment: `Vampire` doesn't override `frighten(int)`, it defines an overload. And of you change it to `long` in the `Monster` class, `Dragon` doesn't override the method either. This is why you should annotate the method `@Override` if you expect the method to be overridden.

Comment: I wouldn't even call this inheritance. You're using the `extends` keyword improperly. To elaborate, `Monster` should be a mold or blueprint for different types of monsters. This isn't achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
inst[i].frighten(i);
```

Because `inst[i]` is of type `Monster`, the compiler has to find a `frighten` method on the `Monster` class which matches the parameter - in the case of your actual code here, it is `frighten(int)`.

It invokes this method on all of the instances of `Monster` that you pass it - it doesn't matter what the class is at runtime, the method is chosen at compile time.

What this means is that the `Vampire.frighten(byte)` method is never invoked - it is an *overload*, rather than an *override*, because the signatures `frighten(int)` and `frighten(byte)` do not match.

If you change the parameter of the `frighten` method to `long` on `Monster`, the compiler can only pick from methods defined on `Monster`, so the only method it knows it can safely invoke on all instances is `frighten(long)`: neither of the subclasses overrides this method - so the behaviour is that of the base class.

If you change the parameter of the `frighten` method to `long` on `Dragon`, it no longer overrides the method in the base class - so the behaviour is that of the base class.

The way to stop this "unexpected" behaviour is to always add @Override to methods that you think override methods in the base class. The compiler will complain if methods with that annotation do not actually override a method on the base class.

Answer (score 8):

You're not passing a `byte` to your instance of `Vampire`; you're passing an `int` with your loop.  Because `Monster` accepts `int`, it is what is being called.

Effectively, you're *overloading* your method, not *overriding* it - you have a method with the same name and two identical signatures.

You really should use homogeneous types when overriding a method so you don't run into issues like this.  Effectively: change the signature of `frighten` in `Vampire` to accept an `int` instead of a `byte`.

Annotating your method with `@Override` will let the compiler help pick things like this up.

```
// Would cause a compilation error since the method isn't overridden
@Override
public boolean frighten(byte x) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not with the vampire class. if the type of x in Monster or drangon class is int, then it works perfectly fine and prints the following : Monster   Monster   Dragon

Comment: @Nain: I wouldn't call that "working fine", given that the intent from the code is to call `frighten` of some class that is a `Monster`.  This is the most apparent issue that I can see in that you're not seeing "Vampire" because you've overloaded your method instead of overrode it.

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to override you can use annotations. Then the compiler will help you discover such errors. For example the compiler would see that there is a mistake here.

```
 class Vampire extends Monster
    {
      @Override 
      boolean frighten(byte x)
      {
       System.out.println("Vampire");
       return true;
      }
     }
```

Comment: Move the annotation a layer lower.  You can't use it on a class.